# Mono, Regex and stack size

Tags: c#, regex, mono, stack-size, dmcs

I'm porting a piece of C# software that uses `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` for parsing out C/C++ includes out of source files. They are fully loaded into memory as a string and then just treated with the regex.

It works perfectly on Windows, but Mono running on Linux fails when trying to parse larger files with a stack overflow exception thrown from deep inside `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Interpreter`.

The code is perfectly correct - it works on Windows.

Is there a way to increase the stack size? Or do I really need to break up larger files into smaller chunks?

**EDIT**: The regex in question looks like this:

```
    /** Regex that matches #include statements. */
    static Regex CPPHeaderRegex = new Regex(    "(([ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]*[<\"](?<HeaderFile>[^\">]*)[\">][^\n]*\n)|([^\n]*\n))*", 
                                                RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture );
```

The sources that cause problems are 300kB (~8k SLOC) and larger.

Mind you that this is not my code, I inherited it.

Comment: you need to show us the `regex` you are using..also how large is the file

Comment: There you go. I think it's pretty clear it's the size of the source that's killing the stack.

Comment: It's not so much the size of the file as the complexity of parsing the regex. Well, it's the combination of the two. If there is a way of splitting these files I would recommend that. OR - What sort of file is it? Can it be parsed with something *built* for parsing the format?

Comment: I pointed out in the question that these are C/C++ source files.

Comment: Ah whoops sorry! It's late...

Comment: So it's not when the regex is made, but when it is used when you get the stackoverflow?  Just asking for 100% clarity.

Comment: See ulimit -s, to make stack size larger.

Comment: Erm, but does that affect the Mono stack size?